How can I persuade a remote server's timitity to output it's sound to the client?
Running timidity on a server, playing sound on the client.
I have written a program in C to help with music practice.  The program makes system calls like:
timidity -T %d -A90 %s/%s.midi >/dev/null &", speed, dir, tune;

This works fine on the local machine.
But I'd like to run my program on a Ubuntu server, where other people can use it.
How can I convince timidity to output the sound on the local machine?  Perhaps it is not possible?

A remote server, how is this possible? Timidity sends midi to the sound card, not over Internet. You want a streaming service
